# how to use lists with class/struct variables in c++

Tags: c#, c++

I have a running `C#` program provided below. I'm trying to convert it into `C++`, but having trouble getting desired output although there are no compilation errors in `C++` program given below.

The `C#` program I am trying to convert is:

```
class Evl_token
{
    public enum Token_type { NAME, NUMBER, SINGLE };
    public Token_type type;
    public string str;
    public int line_no;
}; // class evl_token

List<Evl_token> tokens = new List<Evl_token>()
        {
            //input is below 
            //line 1 module top;
            //line 2 wire in,out;
            //line 3 not(out,in);
            //line 4 endmodule

            new Evl_token {line_no = 1, str = "module", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 1, str = "top", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 1, str = ";", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 2, str = "wire", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 2, str = "in", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 2, str = ",", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 2, str = "out", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 2, str = ";", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = "not", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = "(", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = "out", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = ",", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = "in", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = ")", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 3, str = ";", type = Evl_token.Token_type.SINGLE},
            new Evl_token {line_no = 4, str = "endmodule", type = Evl_token.Token_type.NAME},
        };
```

The corresponding `C++` program I figured out is below:

```
struct evl_token
{
    enum token_type { NAME, NUMBER, SINGLE };
    token_type type;
    std::string str;
    int line_no;
}; //struct evl_token

typedef std::list<evl_token> evl_tokens;

evl_tokens tokens;

evl_token token;

//{
    //input is below 
    //line 1 module top;
    //line 2 wire in,out;
    //line 3 not(out,in);
    //line 4 endmodule
    token.line_no = 1, token.str = "module", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 1, token.str = "top", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 1, token.str = ";", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 2, token.str = "wire", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 2, token.str = "in", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 2, token.str = ",", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 2, token.str = "out", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 2, token.str = ";", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE;
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = "not", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = "(", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = "out", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = ",", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = "in", token.type = evl_token::NAME,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = ")", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 3, token.str = ";", token.type = evl_token::SINGLE,
    token.line_no = 4, token.str = "endmodule", token.type = evl_token::NAME;
//}
tokens.push_back(token);
```

The Output I get in case of `C++` program only shows last line which is line `4`,how should I work with lists in case of `C++` that my list gives me desired output?

Comment: C++'s `list` is a linked list. You're looking for a dynamic array: `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use almost the same syntax as in c#.

- uniform initialization (for `evl_token`) here use the same order as members declare in class
- c# `list` <=> c++ `vector` (c# `LinkedList` <=> c++ `list`)

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct evl_token
{
    enum token_type { NAME, NUMBER, SINGLE };
    int line_no;
    std::string str;
    token_type type;
};

std::vector<evl_token> tokens
{
    { 1,  "module",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 1,  "top",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 1,  ";",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 2,  "wire",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 2,  "in",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 2,  ",",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 2,  "out",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 2,  ";",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 3,  "not",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 3,  "(",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 3,  "out",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 3,  ",",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 3,  "in",  evl_token::token_type::NAME},
    { 3,  ")",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 3,  ";",  evl_token::token_type::SINGLE},
    { 4,  "endmodule",  evl_token::token_type::NAME}
};
```

Comment: Would it be nice if native token_type would exploit strongly typed and tinier `enum class : uint8_t` which c# lacks both?

Comment: @sandthorn isn't c# `enum` strong typed? and yes, I think `enum class` is 
 a good way. but it may cause more confuse here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add every token you have created. Since C++11 you can use list-initialization syntax.

```
struct evl_token
{
    enum token_type { NAME, NUMBER, SINGLE };
    token_type type;
    std::string str;
    int line_no;
}; //struct evl_token

std::vector<evl_token> tokens;
tokens.push_back({ evl_token::NAME,"module",1 });
tokens.push_back({ evl_token::NAME,"top",1 });
tokens.push_back({ evl_token::SINGLE,";",2 });
...
```